# Angular 2 update global state as a side effect of updating a certain state

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I want to achieve setting a global state while also requesting data from an api and storing that in the state as well, but in another location than the global state.

I'm calling this effect (`models.effects.ts`):

```
@Effect() models$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(GET_MODELS)
  .switchMap(() => this.modelsApi.getModels())
  .map(models => ({type: SET_MODELS, payload: models}))
  .catch((err: any) => Observable.of({type: GET_FAILURE, payload: {error: err}}))
```

Now what I want to do is something like this:

```
@Effect() models$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(GET_MODELS)
  .do(() => this.store.dispatch({type: 'SET_LOADING_STATE', payload: true}))
  .switchMap(() => this.modelsApi.getModels())
  .map(models => ({type: SET_MODELS, payload: models}))
  .do(() => this.store.dispatch({type: 'SET_LOADING_STATE', payload: false}))
  .catch((err: any) => Observable.of({type: GET_FAILURE, payload: {error: err}}))
```

As you can see we're dispatching a call to   the `globalReducer` (`global.reducer.ts`):

```
export const GlobalReducer: ActionReducer<any> = (state: IGlobalStorage = {isLoading: false}, action: Action) => {

  switch(action.type) {

    case SET_LOADING_STATE: return Object.assign({}, state, {
      isLoading: action.payload
    });

    default: return state;
  }
}
```

Which would mean that I update the global state `isLoading` before and after we make an http request. However, this solution is both messy and does not work because of the simple fact that it breaks the effect (for whatever reason, I think it's because I call dispatch within the effect).

Preferably I would like to create another effect which listens to `SET_LOADING_STATE` which then calls the `globalReducer` itself, rather than letting the `models$` effect do it directly.

Something like this (from within `global.effects.ts`):

```
@Effect() loadingState$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(SET_LOADING_STATE)
  .do(() => ({type: SET_LOADING_STATE, payload: thePayloadThatWasSent}))
```

But there are 2 problems with that:

1. I don't know how to access a sent payload in an effect.
2. I don't know how to call that effect from within the `models$` effect.

Overall I'm just really confused on how to achieve what I want and there aren't any examples of this as far as I've been able to find.

If you look at this image, I want to update `global.isLoading` when I update `models`:

[image: redux dev tools]

What would be the best way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing an `isLoading` indicator in a central place is a similar to what is sometimes done with error information. One [solution for storing a central error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34482258/6680611) involves using a reducer that ignores actions' types and looks only to see if they contain an `error` property.

If you were to adopt a suitable naming scheme for your effects' action types, you could do much the same thing with `isLoading`.

One possible naming scheme could be:

```
SOME_ACTION_REQUEST
SOME_ACTION_RESPONSE
SOME_ACTION_ERROR
```

With such a scheme, the following reducer would examine the action types and set the `isLoading` state accordingly:

```
export function isLoadingReducer(state: boolean = false, action: Action): boolean {

    if (/_REQUEST$/.test(action.type)) {
        return true;
    } else  if (/(_RESPONSE|_ERROR)$/.test(action.type)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}
```

Using a `boolean` value for `isLoading` assumes that you would not have concurrent asynchronous effects, so if that's an issue, you could extend the reducer to use a counter instead.

If you wire things up this way, the `isLoading` indicator doesn't need to know anything about individual effects and vice versa.