# ngrx Store - How to manage in the UI potentially long lasting actions

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am starting to look into **ngrx/Store** and I am facing the following issue.

From my UI component I need to execute a call to a remote rest API, which potentially can take some time to execute. I want to manage the wait-time showing the user a standard *loading-spinner*.

I am used to manage such situations with code that looks like

```
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: 'Please wait while we load stuff'
        });
   loading.present();
   this.longRunningService.doHeavyWork()
          .subscribe(
              (result) => {
                              // manage result;
                            },
              (err) => console.log(err),
              () => loading.dismiss()
          );
```

The key point (for my problem) in the above code snippet is that when the `longRunningService` completes the `doHeavyWork`  logic (i.e. when the Observable is completed) the loading spinner is dismissed.

Now I want to refactor this code and use **ngrx/Store** **dispatch** mechanism.

My question is how to manage the `loading.dismiss()` logic while using **ngrx/Store** `dispatch` mechanism. In other words I do not know how to close the *loading-spinner* (once the result has been received from the back end rest API) when using **ngrx/Store** dispatch Action mechanism.

Any advice is very much appreciated

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40496998/6680611) and have a look at [ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the [ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects) library to deal with side effects like the "longRunningService"

I learn this from the official example of ngrx. I recommend you to take a look at
https://github.com/ngrx/example-app

The following code is based from the example-app and deal with the loading stuff, please check it.

I assume you are coding a ionic v2 app? because of the LoadingController..

Actions:

```
export const LOAD_STUFF = "LOAD_STUFF";
export const LOAD_STUFF_SUCCESS = "LOAD_STUFF_SUCCESS";
export const LOAD_STUFF_FAIL = "LOAD_STUFF_FAIL";

@Injectable()
export class StuffActions{

  loadStuff() : Action {
    return {
      type: LOAD_STUFF
    };
  }

  loadStuffSuccess(stuff : any []) : Action {
    return {
      type: LOAD_STUFF_SUCCESS,
      payload: stuff
    };
  }
}
```

Reducer

```
export interface State {
  entities: [];
  loading : boolean;
  complete : boolean;
}

const initalState : State = {
  entities: [];
  loading : false;
  complete : false;
};

export function reducer(state = initalState, action) : State {
  switch (action.type) {

    case LOAD_STUFF:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: true,
        complete: false
      });

    case LOAD_STUFF_SUCCESS:
      return {
        complete: true,
        loading: false,
        entities : action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// SELECTORS
export const getLoading = (state: State) => state.loading;
export const getComplete = (state: State) => state.complete;
export const getEntities = (state: State) => state.stuff;
```

effects

```
@Injectable()
export class EnvioEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private _stuffActions : StuffActions, private _longRunningService: LongRunningService ){}

  @Effect() loadStuff: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(LOAD_STUFF)
    .switchMap(() => this._longRunningService.getStuff())
    .map( stuff => this._stuffActions.loadStuffSuccess(stuff));
```

}

selectors index. For selectors I use https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

```
import * as fromStuff from "./stuff";
import {createSelector} from "reselect";
import {ActionReducer, combineReducers, Action} from "@ngrx/store";    

export interface State {
  stuff: fromStuff.State
}

const reducers = {
  stuff: fromStuff.reducer
};

export const reducer: ActionReducer<State> = combineReducers(reducers);

export const rootReducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {
  return reducer(state, action);
};

export const getStuffEntities = createSelector(getOriginState, fromStuff.getEntities);
export const getStuffLoading = createSelector(getOriginState, fromOrigin.getLoading);
export const getStuffComplete = createSelector(getOriginState, fromOrigin.getComplete);
```

Page

```
import * as fromRoot from "../../reducers/index";

@Component({
  selector: 'stuff',
  templateUrl: 'stuff.html'
})
export class StuffPage implements OnDestroy {

  destroy$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
              private _store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
              private _stuffActions: StuffActions) {
  }


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    // HERE I SHOW THE LOADING ANIMATION UNTIL THE LONG RUNNING SERVICE COMPLETE
    this._store.select(fromRoot.getStuffLoading)
      .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      .filter(isloading => isloading)
      .map(() => this.createLoader())
      .do(loading => loading.present())
      .delayWhen(loading => this._store.select(fromRoot.getStuffComplete).filter(complete => complete))
      .map(loading => loading.dismiss())
      .subscribe();

    // LOAD THE STUFF
    this._store.dispatch(this._stuffActions.loadStuff());

  }

  createLoader(): Loading {
    return this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Loading stuff"
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```