# reflux action identifiers on ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I've been surveying several angular2 + webpack + ngrx starter projects for a days.

I've realized several of them are used to use:

```
Injectable()
export class UsersCommons {
  static BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/users';

  static ACTIONS: IActions = {
    LOAD_ALL_START: 'USERS_LOAD_START',
    LOAD_ALL_SUCCESS: 'USERS_LOAD_SUCCESS',
    LOAD_ALL_FAIL: 'USERS_LOAD_FAIL',
    LOAD_ONE_START: 'USER_LOAD_START',
    LOAD_ONE_SUCCESS: 'USER_LOAD_SUCCESS',
    LOAD_ONE_FAIL: 'USER_LOAD_FAIL',
    UPDATE_START: 'USER_UPDATE_START',
    UPDATE_SUCCESS: 'USER_UPDATE_SUCCESS',
    UPDATE_FAIL: 'USER_UPDATE_FAIL',
    //...
  }
}
```

I don't quite figure out why each action has a `[_START|_SUCCESS|_FAIL]`. Could somebody explain me what does this pattern stand for?

Comment: Give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487872/angular-2-update-global-state-as-a-side-effect-of-updating-a-certain-state/40496998#40496998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a naming convention. It could allow you to do a regular expression check in logic later on or it might just be useful for readability. You could just as easily add additional states and call them `[_START|_PENDING|_ERROR|_SUCCESS|_COMPLETE]`.