# NGRX passing reducer state into components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a tasks reducer which represents the following object:

```
{
    error: false,
    loading: false,
    tasks: []
}
```

Now, the object is passed down into a dumb component:

```
<task-list tasks="tasks$ | async"></task-list>
```

The thing I don't like is the fact that to access the list of tasks I have to use `tasks.tasks`. I've considered passing `error`, `loading` and `tasks` into the component separately as well as using getters. However, this presents another issue when I pass in say `tasks` and `users` ... I'd had to pass in a `loading` and `error` property for both `tasks` and `users`

Is this an awkward issue that people just accept or is there a better way around this?

Comment: If you are keeping separate `error` and `loading` states for tasks and users, you might want to reconsider and and instead store general purpose `error` and `loading` states elsewhere. That would significantly simplify your tasks and users reducers. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34482258/6680611 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/40496998/6680611 for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Are you bothered by tasks.tasks ?

What's wrong with using a slice of state called `tasks`, that would contain

```
{
    error: false,
    loading: false,
    currentTasks: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer, but I always say if something looks intuitively off then it pays off to invest 5 minutes into looking for a better way. Here I would rename the reducer and input:

```
<task-list state="taskListState$ | async"></task-list>
```