# Redux error handling and the Flux Standard Action

Tags: error-handling, redux, standards

I'm new to Redux. I have seen that [Flux have proposed a standard way to make error handling](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action) as an element of their Flux Standard Action. I'm new to Redux so I am a bit confused about what they meaning by handling standardly the errors. 
I have visited the Flux Github page since [the Redux documentation recommends to get an eye on it](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions).

I have seen some discussion on the web about error handling in Redux. I'm just wondering if [the solution I have seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403269/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-a-fetch-error-in-react-redux) complies with the Flux Standard Actions standards.

If anyone can just enlight us on this subject and explains us why it complies or not it would be very great.

Thanks